# How to show if two two matrices are similar, then their images under a polynomial are similar?

Tags: matrices

I have a quick question.

Let $A,B$ be square matrix. And let $p(t)=a_kt^k+\cdots+a_1t+a_0)$ be a polynomial.

Prove that if $A$ and $B$ are similar then $p(A)$ and $p(B)$ are similar.

*Proof:* If $A$ and $B$ are similar there exists a non singular matrix $P$ such that 
$B=P^{-1}AP$

We then place the matrix A in the polynomial equation then

$P(A)=a_kA^k+\cdots+a_1A^1+a_0I$
So then we must show for a nonsingular matrix $P$

$P^{-1}P(A), \quad  P=  P(B)$

So from the left

\begin{align}
& =P^{-1}(a_kA^k+\cdots+a_2A^2+A_1A+a_0I)P \\[01pt]
& =a_kP^{-1}A^{k}P+\cdots+a_1P^{-1}A^1P+a_0P^{-1}IP
\end{align}

and we for any natural number $K$  then$B^K=(P^{-1}AP)^k$

so then

\begin{align}
& =a_kB^k+\cdots+a_1 B+a_0 I \\[10pt]
& =P(B)
\end{align}

so $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ are similar.

Comment: A caveat: similar polynomials are equal, since polynomial multiplication is commutative

Comment: @CarryonSmiling The title's use of polynomial is a misnomer: it doesn't refer to the polynomials being similar, but the images of the two matrices under the same polynomial.

Comment: Since $A$ and $B$ are similar, $B=P^{-1}AP$ for some nonsingular
$P$, by definition. Moreover, 
$$
B^{n}=\left(P^{-1}AP\right)^{n}=\underbrace{P^{-1}AP\cdots P^{-1}AP}_{n\text{ times}}=P^{-1}A^{n}P.
$$
Therefore,
$$
p(B)=\sum_{n=0}^{k}a_{n}B^{n}=\sum_{n=0}^{k}a_{n}P^{-1}A^{n}P=P^{-1}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{k}a_{n}A^{n}\right)P=P^{-1} p(A) P.
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that seems about right. The key point to note is that $(P^{-1}AP)^k =P^{-1}A^kP $.

Personally I find it easier to write the other way round. We have $B=P^{-1}AP $, so $p (B) = a_kB^k +\dots +a_1 B + a_0 I = a_k(P^{-1}AP)^k +\dots +a_1 P^{-1}AP + a_0 I = a_kP^{-1}A^kP + \dots  +a_1 P^{-1}AP + a_0 P^{-1}IP  = P^{-1}(a_kA^k + \dots + a_1A + a_0I )P = P^{-1}p(A)P.$

Comment: Ok that makes sense